# C# 'LBImqP.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load'

Tags: c#

Please someone help me, i stuck at this error and i dont now how to fix it.

Error code: 'LBImqP.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load' and no extension method 'Form1_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'LBImqP.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace LBImqP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=lbimqp;User ID=root;password='server1234'");
        int i;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from login where username='"+user.Text+"' and password='"+pass.Text+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            if (i == 0)
            {
                wrong.Text = "Benutzername oder Passwort ist falsch!";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hide();
                mainscreen ms = new mainscreen();
                ms.Show();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        private void pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pass.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error at button1_Click, and Form1_Load

it would be greatful when someone can help me please.

Comment: do you know anything about sql injection?

Comment: yes, but thats not the problem

Comment: Okay, you will have bigger problems soon.
you are missing assembly references.

Comment: Have a idea how i fix this problem? with the error

Comment: you should fix your sql injection vulnerabilities with parameterization. In principle you should never write code like this. This example shows the string concatenation of sql queries from user inputs. That is a big security risk.

Comment: Don't make us guess which line is throwing the exception.  I'm *guessing* you created the load event and then deleted the code, but the event is still wired.

Comment: find what is asking for 'Form1_Load'  and 'LBImqP.Form1' and possibly remove it because it seems like those things are not defined in your code..

Comment: Then show me how i fix it;)

Comment: If you have an error showing in the Error box (View - Error List), double click on it and it will take you to the designer file.  Delete the line that is highlighted that shows the load event being subscribed.

Comment: When i delete the line then it comes more and more error's

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B72Upd57dOO5Si1PcF9RRHRvY0E

Comment: Did you rebuild the project?  Those messages (I don't quite have the translation) sounds like the program is running or something is using that exe.

Comment: I Know but i dont using the exe, its not running. and this is a new project

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus product running?

Comment: yes i have avast antivirus

Comment: avast doesn't work well with visual studio.

Comment: wtf i looked the at the error and it realized the exe is used

Comment: and i stopped the process and its working ._.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attaching an event inside the Form1 designer with event handler `Form1_Load`, and the event handler is not defined in Form1 class.

Or the namespaces of the designer class and form class are not identical.